# Does work stay in Germany count as travel history for UK work visa?

Tags: germany, working-visas, uk-visa, blue-card, skilled-migration

I am applying for the UK skilled worker visa and I need to fill out the travel history for myself and my family.

[image]

I have been staying in Germany on a long term work visa for the last 1-3 years. Shall I include my stay in Germany in the travel history? I went to Switzerland on vacation and I do not need to apply for any visa due to my German residence. Shall I include that travel in my travel history as well?

Comment: What exactly does the question in the application form say? Presumably the application will ask you to supply details of your immigration status and residence in Germany anyway, if that’s the case ‘travel history’ will refer to anywhere you’ve visited, regardless of whether you needed a visa or not.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have updated the question. Yes, I would be mentioning immigration status and residence in Germany anyway. Then do I need to mention travel from Germany to India as travel history? I am a Indian citizen.

Comment: They’re looking for proof of compliance with immigration rules for any country visited. That isn’t relevant for return visits to your country of citizenship, IMHO. https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/974078/skilled-worker-caseworker-guidance-v2.0ext.pdf#page13

Comment: Why does the question express such uncertainty about the duration of your stay in Germany?